# Data binding behaving unexpected between fragments and activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-databinding

So I'm trying to figure out why I can't override a data bound property `mainActivity.toolbarViewConfig.title.value = "help me please"`. The property seems to be set only once and this will either work in my activity or in Fragment A. If I try to give the property a value in Fragment B, that would not work. If I try to override the property by setting a click-listener for a button in the activity, that would not work. So obviously there seems to be something strange going on with the binding. All kind of suggestions would be appreciated. I have been sitting scratching my head 4 days in a row. Please help me not become bald.

Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


    val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    binding.toolbarViewConfig = toolbarViewConfig
    setContentView(binding.root)


    window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
    findViewById<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar).setupWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)}
```

Fragment A:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    val mainActivity = activity!! as MainActivity
    mainActivity.toolbarViewConfig.title.value = "This works!" //Works fine. 

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
}
```

Fragment B:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
{
    val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(GoOnlineViewModel::class.java)

    val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentSellerGoOnlineBinding>(
        inflater, R.layout.fragment_seller_go_online,
        container, false
    ).apply {
        this.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        this.viewModel = viewModel}

    val mainActivity = activity!! as MainActivity
    mainActivity.toolbarViewConfig.title.value = "This does not work" //When I navigate from Fragment A to B this will not be set

    viewModel.navigationCommand.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        when(it) {
            is NavigationCommand.To ->
                Navigation.findNavController(requireView()).navigate(it.directions)
        }
    })


    return binding.root
}
```

ToolbarViewConfig:

```
class ToolbarViewConfig(
var title: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData(""))
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>

    <variable
        name="toolbarViewConfig"
        type="my.app.willow.models.ToolbarViewConfig" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{toolbarViewConfig.title}"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"/>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If you switch Fragment B to do the toolbar stuff first, before the `DataBindingUtil` call and related setup, does it work? That would more closely match your Fragment A setup, where you update the toolbar prior to inflating the layout for the fragment.

Comment: @CommonsWare unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: OK, next test: comment out most of Fragment B's `onCreateView()` and have it more closely match Fragment A, using ordinary `inflate()` to set up the layout. This isn't what you want long-term, but it will help determine if the nested data binding itself is the problem. If this now works, then perhaps there's some limitation of using data binding both in the activity and one of its fragments. If this also fails though, then there's something else about Fragment B that is different, and we'd need to figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to assign a `lifecycleOwner` in your `ActivityMainBinding`. Without it, your `Activity` will never listen for changes and will just read the current value once.

I believe that `FragmentA` creates it's view and sets the title during `ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)`. So in the next line when you set up `toolbarViewConfig` in your `ActivityMainBinding`, it can already read the initial value of the title `LiveData` (set by `FragmentA`), but will never react to any later changes done in `FragmentB`.

Comment: Thank you so much, It now works! I just had to set `binding.lifecycleOwner = this` in my acitivty